# How do I remove unwanted fonts?

Tags: fonts

[image: Menu showing many Noto fonts]

I can see the Noto fonts in Adobe Illustrator but I’m not able find from Library or font book how to remove them. Please help me to clean up this font family.

Comment: Do a system-wide search in Finder for "Noto Sans" and see if you can find it that way.

Comment: Too bad Adobe *still* does not have the same "Find Font.." functionality across their entire "Suite" of programs. With InDesign, you'd just type any text in that font and then have it look up in the Finder/Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your PC: Control Panel - All Control Panel Settings - Adjust Computer Settings - Fonts - You will find most fonts in that folder. You can also do a search for 'True Type folder' and delete them from there.

Comment: The OP appears to be using a Mac, which does not have a Control Panel.

Comment: I used MAC's for a long time. That is why I added to do a search for the 'True Type' (maybe  should have added 'Fonts' too) folder. They used to reside in the Adobe program folder. With PS CC they  do not seem to be loaded there. From Adobe PS help -*To make fonts available to Photoshop and other Adobe Creative Suite applications, install them in these system folders: **Windows - Windows/Fonts ---Mac OS -Library/Fonts**.